# How to include the number of runs in the graph title

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am doing a simulation using `python 3x`. I have made a graph using `matplotlib`. I want to include the value of `N` i.e. the number of runs in the title of the graph. How this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible ways: (I commented out one of them)

```
N = 100 # Runs

# Way 1
plt.title('Number of runs = %d' %N) 

# Way 2
# plt.title('Number of runs = {}'.format(N))
```

**Sample plot**

[image]